# React Native Upload word doc/PDF to Google Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, storage

How can I use React Native to create a upload file screen and upload word doc/pdf and save it in Google Firebase storage???

I have seen solution to save image, but not word doc/pdf

Thanks

Comment: You might use dropzoneJS for react :
https://react-dropzone.js.org/

Comment: @MohammadTbeishat Any solution for mobile app using React Native?? Thanks

Comment: As react native is based on reactjs I thought it's okay to use dropzonejs.. Sorry, I didn't use react native. But this package sounds good: https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady